# Javascript Date parse

Tags: javascript, date

In javascript `Date.parse('2015-04-02')` returns `1427932800000` which is the same result as `Date.parse('2015-04-02 03:00:00')`, what can explain this behaviour?

Comment: I'd guess UTC and your local time zone.

Comment: `Date.parse('2015-04-02')` returns `1427932800000` and `Date.parse('2015-04-02 03:00:00')` returns `1427923800000` for me. Definitely, your timezone would be +3:00.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript Date.parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse)

Comment: yeah my time zone is UTC+3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Date depends on your local timezone. but the returned number is un UTC. 
if you want to convert you can do (I think) :

```
var date = new Date('2015-04-02 03:00:00')
date.setMinutes(-date.getTimezoneOffset())
```

Comment: BTW be careful using the "-" separator it is not recognized by firefox

Comment: on my browser chrome(42) Date.UTC() returns NaN

Comment: And what if you user new Date() instead of date.Parse ?

Comment: I changed the code, you should try. It worked with my timezone (UTC+1)

Comment: i think it should be +date.getTimezoneOffset() to return it to 2015-04-02 00:00:00